# javascript : changing <DIV> onclick value

Tags: javascript

I have a `<DIV>` which I'm using as a **button** like this :

```
<div id='project_1_task_2_is_done' 
class='button_style_1_small' onClick='taskIsDone(1,2,"y");'>
Is done?
</div>
```

I want to change the **onClick** string value to `taskIsDone(1,2,"n")` once the user clicks on it, and then, when it clicks again, back to `taskIsDone(1,2,"y")` and so on.

I'm trying to accomplish this from the **taskIsDone** javascript function such as

```
if(is_done=='n'){
    document.getElementById('project_' + project_id + '_task_' + task_id + '_is_done')
.onclick = "taskIsDone(" + project_id + "," + task_id + ",'y');"
}
```

but it's not working.

I looked over the net to more than 7-8 examples, most from here (Stackoverflow) but I'm not finding the answer to my question (which is basically changing dynamically the **onclick** string for that **DIV** id. I don't want to run a function, as most of the examples i found present, just want to change the **onclick** string value, modifying "y" to "n", and again "y", etc, for each click on the **div** button.

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/wnw0oskd/

You can change it as an attribute, as the alert shows `onlick` of the element is not 'taskIsDone(1,2,"y");' but a function.

```
document.getElementById('project_' + project_id + '_task_' + task_id + '_is_done').setAttribute("onclick", "taskIsDone(" + project_id + "," + task_id + ",'n'");"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print the current value of `document.getElementById('your_div').onclick` you realize tht it's not the string `taskIsDone(1,2,"y");`, but it's:

```
function (event) {
    taskIsDone(1,2,"y");
}
```

So, if you want to change the value of `.onclick`, assign it one such a function.

Example (toggle the value of `.onclick` between `a()` and `b()`):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            function a() {
                alert("a()");
                document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function(event) {
                    b();
                }
            }
            function b() {
                alert("b()");
                document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function(event) {
                    a();
                }
            }
        </script>
        <div id="foo" style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 20px; width: 200px; height: 50px; background-color: red;" onclick="a();">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for kindly coding for me...i'm using the simplest answer here, but i'm sure all contributors have great answers, and also other people can learn some more from these examples as well. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div id='project_1_task_2_is_done' 
class='button_style_1_small' >
Is done?
</div>
```

---

```
 var check=false;
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('button_style_1_small');
button.click =function(){
      if(check==false){
            check=true;
            taskIsDone(1,2,"n");
        }else{
          check=false;
          taskIsDone(1,2,"y");

          }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question specifically, try setting "onlick" to a function instead of a string:

```
if (is_done=='n'){
  var elmt = document.getElementById(...); // arguments omitted for brevity
  elmt.onclick = function(project_id, task_id) {
    taskIsDone(project_id, task_id, 'y');
  }
}
```

Having said that, though, there are better ways of doing this sort of thing. You could, for instance keep your state in a data attribute attached to the div:

```
<div id='project_1_task_2_is_done' data-done="no"
   class='button_style_1_small' onClick='toggleDone(ev, 1, 2)'>
   Is done?
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDone(ev, projectId, taskId) {
   var elmt = ev.target
   elmt.dataset.done = elmt.dataset.done == "yes" ? "no" : "yes"
}
</script>
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp